# How to retrieve one document from collection in Firebase & Ionic?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have this following code to retrieve all the documents from one collection :

```
public postCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
public posts: Observable<Post[]>;

constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
   this.postCollection = firestore.collection<Post>('Posts');
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ...data};
          });
        })
    );
}
```

So now, how can i do the same job but for only one document (i know his id) ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument

Comment: Yeah it works great ! Thanks a lot :)